# Why would vshost work when my application doesn't?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, 64-bit, scsf

I am attempting to debug an error while loading my x64 application and am receiving an "MyAPP has stopped working" immediately before the first line of code in main().

What I am wondering is why when I use the debugger in Visual Studio 2010 (myapp.vshost.exe process) I can step through the code just fine and everything appears to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - ansering my own question for future reference.

The main application was being profiled by Application Verifier (x64) which was causing a stack overflow.  As applications under test is set in the registry, I had completely forgotten that this was still set in the list of processes to test.  Since the vshost process is using it's own .exe it was not being profiled... no crash!